# Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'. > 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) in android studio

Tags: android, exception, gradle

I am using the Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1. The app was working fine before but then I tried to implement some changes in gradle in order to implement Ktor. I made the following changes in the gradle after that it started giving me the error.

```
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "1.8.0" apply false

    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.3")
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:2.1.3")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:2.1.3")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:2.1.3")

    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization")
```

and now trying to run the application but it is giving me the following error

```
    Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 
   'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
    Consider using JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain
```

Here is the `build.gradle.kts(:app)`

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.orderapp"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.orderapp"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.3")
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:2.1.3")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:2.1.3")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:2.1.3")

    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.3")

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}
```

Here is the `build.gradle.kts(Project)`

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.1" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "1.8.0" apply false

}
```

I do not know why this is causing the error? What can I change in the code to make it work? Thanks in advance